# Is "close helmet" correct? Why/why not?

Tags: nouns, word-usage

I've been debating this for a while now with a comrade of mine. Wikipedia (and others) give "close helmet" as a type of medieval helmet.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_helmet

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/close+helmet

My compatriot argues that, as-is, this doesn't make sense, that it should be either "closed helmet" (with an extra D) or "close-helmet" (hyphenated). I say "close helmet" is perfectly fine, and simple Google searches turn up more results for this form of it, but I can't find a convincing argument for *why* it is correct other than because it seems to be the most common usage.

My friend says that "close helmet" is only correct if "close" is an adjective, as in "she sat *close* to me", but that doesn't really make sense for a type of helmet, since ALL helmets can be considered "close" to one when worn.

Yet, using "close" as a verb ("I shall *close* the door") doesn't really make grammatical sense either. The defining feature of this type of helmet is that it can open and close (or it is related to the opening/closing; I'm not entirely sure of the details), so "close helmet" makes some kind of sense, but I don't know a grammatical construction that allows this.

Or is this just a relic of older English that has survived into the present?

At first, I was sure that "close helmet" was correct, but the more I think about it the more confused I make myself. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, according to this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_helmet) it is *close* as in "close the door."

> The *close helmet*, also called the *close helm* was a military helmet worn by knights and other men-at-arms in the Late Medieval and Renaissance eras. It was also used by some heavily armoured, pistol-armed, cuirassiers into the mid 17th century. It was a fully enclosing helmet with a pivoting visor and integral bevor.

Also, being a technical and historical term, it simply is; even though it sounds strange and unfamiliar to our modern ear.

Several senses of the word as listed [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/close) are readily identifiable as sources for the usage.

Comment: Aside: I thought for sure this would be in the OED, and I could add that reference to the answer, but I couldn't find it there last night.  Three or four pages on *close*, with related senses, so I might have missed it.

Answer (score 2):

If "close" is a specific technical term for a type of helmet then "close helmet" would be just as correct as "Steel helmet" or "Norman helmet"

Answer (score 1):

*Close* is sometimes used as a modifier instead of *closed*; a well-known example is [*close-minded.*](http://grammarist.com/spelling/closed-minded/)

Comment: Also, while _close_ is usually pronounced kloʊs when used as an adjective, I believe it's kloʊz for these senses – essentially, it's just _closed_ with the D clipped off.